# dynamically add a sequential date column to a data frame with a starting with each date is repeated N times in consecutive rows

Tags: python, dataframe, date, repeat

I've got the following data.frame:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

data = {
    'Column1': [random.randint(1, 100) for _ in range(9)],
    'Column2': [random.uniform(0, 1) for _ in range(9)],
    'Column3': [chr(random.randint(65, 90)) for _ in range(9)],
    'Column4': [random.choice(['A', 'B', 'C']) for _ in range(9)]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

   Column1   Column2 Column3 Column4
0       87  0.208179       M       C
1       85  0.049071       Q       C
2        4  0.474926       X       C
3       35  0.966357       L       B
4       58  0.295134       C       B
5       23  0.633367       R       B
6       87  0.069583       V       B
7       83  0.427594       N       A
8       16  0.592413       R       C
```

I'd like to add a new sequential DATE column with entries starting from a chosen start_date (= '2022-01-01'), so that each date is repeated N (=2) times, for the whole dataset. I also would like to add another column called SHIFT with n (=2) alternative selected_values=['Day','Night'].

```
## desired output for N=2 and start_date = '2022-01-01', and n=2 with selected_values = ['Day','Night']

   Column1   Column2 Column3 Column4   DATE         SHIFT
0       87  0.208179       M       C   2022-01-01    Day
1       85  0.049071       Q       C   2022-01-01    Night
2        4  0.474926       X       C   2022-01-02    Day
3       35  0.966357       L       B   2022-01-02    Night
4       58  0.295134       C       B   2022-01-03    Day
5       23  0.633367       R       B   2022-01-03    Night
6       87  0.069583       V       B   2022-01-04    Day
7       83  0.427594       N       A   2022-01-04    Night
8       16  0.592413       R       C   2022-01-05    Day
```

**- N, n, selected_values, and start_date are all dynamic. with n = number of elements in selected_values**

to make it more clear, here's the desired output for different parameters:

```
## desired output for N=2 and start_date = '2022-01-01', and n=3 with selected_values = ['Day','Night','Afternoon']

   Column1   Column2 Column3 Column4   DATE         SHIFT
0       87  0.208179       M       C   2022-01-01    Day
1       85  0.049071       Q       C   2022-01-01    Night
2        4  0.474926       X       C   2022-01-02    Afternoon
3       35  0.966357       L       B   2022-01-02    Day
4       58  0.295134       C       B   2022-01-03    Night
5       23  0.633367       R       B   2022-01-03    Afternoon
6       87  0.069583       V       B   2022-01-04    Day
7       83  0.427594       N       A   2022-01-04    Night
8       16  0.592413       R       C   2022-01-05    Afternoon
```

Comment: What is the meaning of the 'n' of the SHIFT column? If n=1, what should the column look like? n=3, same question.

Comment: if n=1, then selected value would be only ['Day'] or only ['Night']. if n=3, the selected values would be ['Day', 'Night', 'Afternoon'], as examples.

Comment: so 'n' is always equal to the number of shift? Are the names of the shifts fixed? If so, what are they?

Comment: yes, i edited my question so that is clear. n is the number of elements in selected values for shift. shift elements could be anything. e.g. morning, night, day, afternoon, etc. Please see second example of desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def add_dates_shifts(df, start_date, N, shifts, n):
    dates = [datetime.fromisoformat(start_date) + timedelta(days=i) for i in df.index for _ in range(N)][:len(df)]
    df["DATE"] = dates
    df["SHIFT"] = [shifts[i] for _ in df.index for i in range(n)][:len(df)]
```

```py
add_dates_shifts(df, "2022-01-01", 2, ["Day", "Night"], 2)

   Column1   Column2 Column3 Column4       DATE  SHIFT
0       48  0.283085       J       C 2022-01-01    Day
1       76  0.896891       J       B 2022-01-01  Night
2       58  0.867856       Z       B 2022-01-02    Day
3       60  0.175652       H       C 2022-01-02  Night
4       50  0.222947       S       A 2022-01-03    Day
5       36  0.753228       A       A 2022-01-03  Night
6       48  0.032319       W       B 2022-01-04    Day
7       10  0.412104       T       A 2022-01-04  Night
8       61  0.266018       Q       A 2022-01-05    Day
```

Comment: thank you! that works and it's very quick